# Java file won't open

Tags: java, class

I was working on a java file earlier, then when I went back to it it says it is a CLASS file and now won't open. This is what appears if I open it in JCreator:
Êþº¾

dialNumber
countEqual
SourceFile
order.java

S²
L=+¾¢
M*¾½

ú
L½

Same happens if I open it in notepad.

How will I go about opening this file?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what happened between you creating the fine and you getting the error? What software did you use to write code in the file? Did you try to compile it? How?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you compiled a .java file to a .class byte code representation.  You should still have the original source.

Update: Are you saying there's no .java file anywhere on your disk?  You have this issue if you try to open the .java file?

Sounds like you royally screwed up.  You must have overwritten your .java source with the .class file.

You should re-create your .java file and try again.

I'd also recommend that you not use JCreator.  Your Java knowledge seems shallow; see if you can open it with a text editor and leave the IDE out of it.  Create .java in a text editor; compile to .class file on the command line in a shell.

Voting to close due to insufficient information.

Comment: This came up when i found the .java file:

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        //compiled code
        throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
    }

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open the compiled bytecode of the file (which is *.class*) and not the source file (which is *.java*). Former one is generated by the Java compiler and it's the real file that can be executed by the JVM.

Search for the correct file and you'll solve the problem.

Comment: This came up when i found the .java file

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { //compiled code throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code"); } ETC

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the `.class` file. A class file is the compiled code that the JVM will interpret to run your program. You need to find the `.java` file and open that.

Comment: This came up when i found the .java file

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { //compiled code throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code"); }  ETC

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new one but using a different editor. Jcreator is easy to use but when you try open the src file in another OS or editor you will find weird characters.

If your class file is ok why not decompile the class instead recovery the src?